# How do I reference class object with String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, object, properties, reference

I need to iterate through array values and reference class objects.. like this..  how do I do this in C# .net??

in C# how do you reference a Class Object with a String??

ie...

```
 public class GlobalVars
 {

     private static Object[] _prevval1;

     public static Object[] prevval1
     {
         get { return _prevval1; }

         set { _prevval1 = value; }
     }
 }



 string[] str = new string[]'
 str[0] = "val1";

 string value = Convert.toString(GlobalVars.prev + str[0] + [0].toString());
```

This (last line above) does not work.. how so how do I do this??

I just used a CASE statement, comment or suggestions are welcome.... thanks for your help and advice.

```
        string[] curArray = new string[6];
        curArray[0] = "AUD/USD";
        curArray[1] = "EUR/USD";
        curArray[2] = "GBP/USD";
        curArray[3] = "USD/CAD";
        curArray[4] = "USD/CHF";
        curArray[5] = "USD/JPY";

        for (int i = 0; i < curArray.Length; i++ )
        {
            // Get Symbols
            DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();
            dtrow["Symbol"] = curArray[i].ToString();
            string sym = curArray[i].ToString();

            // Get Ask Price
            string ask = "-";
            dtrow["AskPrice"] = ask.ToString();

            if (GlobalVars.prevEURUSD != null)
            {
                switch (sym)
                {
                    case "AUD/USD":
                        dtrow["AskPrice"] = GlobalVars.prevAUDUSD[3].ToString();
                        break;
                    case "EUR/USD":
                        dtrow["AskPrice"] = GlobalVars.prevEURUSD[3].ToString();
                        break;
                    case "GBP/USD":
                        dtrow["AskPrice"] = GlobalVars.prevGBPUSD[3].ToString();
                        break;
                    case "USD/CAD":
                        dtrow["AskPrice"] = GlobalVars.prevUSDCAD[3].ToString();
                        break;
                    case "USD/CHF":
                        dtrow["AskPrice"] = GlobalVars.prevUSDCHF[3].ToString();
                        break;
                    case "USD/JPY":
                        dtrow["AskPrice"] = GlobalVars.prevUSDJPY[3].ToString();
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does GlobalVars define a member or property called "prev"?

Comment: It doesn't look like your code would even compile. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? What language do you normally use?

Comment: JB no the properties are prevAUD/USD prevUSD/CHF etc and the str[] = str[0] = "AUD/USD" etc

Comment: repo - i know it does not compile; I am trying to update the prices in a Global Variable that is holding a data stream of prices into a datatable that will kick off a function to trigger and event (trade of a currency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a `Dictionary<string, object>` ?
You can access the Keys property to iterate through the keys.

**EDIT**
Based on your comment:

```
class ProductPriceInfo 
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public DateTime PriceTimeStamp {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
...
Dictionary<string, ProductPriceInfo> _prices = new Dictionary<string, ProductPriceInfo>();
// Adding a price
_prices.Add(myProduct.ID, myProduct);

// updating the price
if(_prices[myProductv2.ID].PriceTimeStamp < myProductv2.PriceTimeStamp)
{
    _prices[myProductv2.ID].PriceTimeStamp = myProductv2.PriceTimeStamp;
    _prices[myProductv2.ID].Price = myProductv2.Price;
}
```

Would that work?

Comment: I think I understand your comment based on Jim's answer... I would then just need to keep the order of the values all the same to reference different properties.. (I think).

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier for us to help you if we understand what you want to accomplish. Forget the code you wrote tell us what it is that you want to achieve from a functional point of view.

Comment: I am storing streams of pricing data in Global Arrays that hold the last price, then I run functions of these prices.. there are too many to store all of them in tables so I only hold the last one and then I see if it's older than x seconds and store it.. but I want to use the latest price for other functions so I am referencing them as above

Comment: That's very interesting... I am sure it's more 'standard' C#... and would help me reference the prices using index values etc...  but seems to add a bit more complexity than I am currently doing.

Comment: I just added a case statement see above.. any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: the more I look at the answer above, the more I like it... i think this is the answer to what I need to do, it's simple and functional.....!!!! )

Comment: THIS WORKS GREAT.. I LOVE IT... THANKS!

Comment: No problem, that is what this site is for.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but it looks like you're trying to create a collection that stores objects and is indexed by a string key.

There are several different .NET classes that will help you.  Probably the most common are  `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`, and `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`.  If the items in your collection are all of the same type, I would recommend `Dictionary`.  If they can be of many different types, then you might look more closely at `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: hmm I am curious... I use a Class which stores an object that is an Array of Strings and that is what I use to store data.. are you saying that one of these other class would be easier ? What advantages would I have ?  I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I get it.. it's like the ArrayCollection in Flex... etc.. So I was wondering where this was in C#

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do the following:

```
string value = Convert.toString(GlobalVars.prev.ToString() + str[0]);
```

but I don't that's what you're looking for, because that will (generally) just give you the type name. If you have control over the classes that will be in that array, you can override the ToString in the object and present whatever you want:

```
override string ToString()
{
         return "MyObject|FirstName:" + this.FirstName + "|LastName:" + this.LastName; // etc.
}
```

But if you don't, then the only thing I can suggest is maybe a serializer. But even then, there are things that the object has to support. Barring that, you can reflect the properties and represent them in string format.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: that's not going to work, it is the same as I have above... I am trying to reference the class property of a global array

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use reflection on that GlobalVars to get hold of PropertyInfo (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zkfcy34(v=VS.95).aspx) and GetMethod to get the value. Not very complicated.. I am sure there are examples on the net. Look up Reflection, PropertyInfo, GetGetMethod..

Comment: I have looked into this; I have not figured it out yet, it is a little complicated at first glance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355090/using-propertyinfo-getvalue actually might be the answer..

Comment: Did the recommendation help? Please post whatever worked.. :)

Comment: I will post the complete solution below.. I really just wanted to keep it simple, so I just kept the data in a string that was converted to an object array... then used a case statement instead of serializing the data.  It just seems a lot easier to me. I posted the case statement Above - not below.