# Is there a node.js package for these 3 types of advanced json searches?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I was investigating how to return the value of a nested property property and there isn't a native way to do it so on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key) question a user responded with a pretty good implementation.

Then I went on to look up ways of [finding all properties with a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values) and lastly [looking up the value of a property just via the property name even if it's nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027366/how-to-find-an-object-property-value-from-a-nested-objected-group-using-a-string)

Is there an npm/node.js package which has these kinds of functions built it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to lodash library: https://lodash.com/docs/#get

Comment: Thanks that's basically perfect, haven't checked if they have those other functions but oh well. I'm just gonna use the package instead of including the function on every model I make :)